# Getting credentials of specified user

Tags: c#, sharepoint, networking, credentials

I wrtitting a windows service. This service has to connect SharePoint service and get data different for each user. sharePoint service return data based on user credentials whitch are set before calling service.
How can I get user credentials by user name and user domain if the service can be run under any account that needs to get this credentials?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you add the sharepoint service (web reference or service reference) there are different methods to send credentials with the request.

With a web reference you would add a `NetworkCredentials` object along the lines of:

```
SomerService ws = ... //instantiate your service
ws.PreAuthenticate = true;
ws.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredentials("username","pw","domain");
```

if it´s a service reference with `wsHttpBinding` then something like this:

```
Service client = ... //instantiate your service
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "domain\\username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

Then you need to store the username/password for each user you are retrieving content for.

If this is a pass-thru service where the client accesses your service and it access sharepoint on the users behalf you have to set up Kerberos authentication and allow impersonation to pass thru. Maybe you could expand on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: That's right, but what have I do if I don't know user passwords?
As far as I understood googling this issue - it is impossible.

Comment: You cannot impersonate a user without you either knowing how to log on as that user, or the user instantiating the call, and allowing the credentials to delegate to another application context. Your other option is having a user with access to all content in SharePoint, and using that instead. Could you elaborate on what content you are trying to access based on other users?

Comment: Where do I do this: "set up Kerberos authentication and allow impersonation to pass thru"

Comment: Since this is a windows service, it's not an option. Your app will either run as the user running the service, or you have to provide the login credentials. Your best option is to give your service account full read access in SharePoint.

Comment: where is "SomerService" - what reference to use to access SomerService?